# How to convert my Apex class into a REST service

Tags: apex

Hello I have already written an apex class that when given a distance and some other parameters returns the nearest stores to the those parameters. I would like to turn this class into a rest service and I am a little stuck in this because most of the trailhead examples have just one parameters in them. Can someone please help me get started on this. url would look something like this:

```
getStores?latitude=90.2&longitude=-1477&distance=10&postal_code=23456&country=us
which would return this:
stores = [
{
name: ' Great Center,
location: {lat: 90.7, lng: -143.5},
address: ‘125 Fake Blvd, Grand Rapids, TX 23456 US’,
distance : 3 miles,
Phone : 852-446-3569,
StudioLocationId: XYZTY,
Studio Type: Indoor
},
{
name: ' Awesome Center,
location: {lat: 90.790091, lng: -146.968285},
address: ‘126 Fake Blvd, Grand Rapids, TX 23456 US’,
distance : 4 miles,
Phone : 852-446-3969,
StudioLocationId: CVTYU,
Studio Type: indoor

}]
```

The class I have written to return the stores for a given address is:

```
public with sharing class StoreReturner{

    public List<Account> storesList {get; set;}
    public String err {get; set;}


    public static StoresReturner initClass(Id contactId) {
        //create a class instance
        StoresReturner obj = new StoresReturner();

        //Initialize
        obj.storeList = new List<Account>();

        //This Contact (Consumer)
        Contact con = [SELECT MailingAddress, MailingLatitude, MailingLongitude FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId LIMIT 1];
        Double lat = 0;
        Double lon = 0;
        lat = con.MailingLatitude;
        lon = con.MailingLongitude;
        if (lat <> null && lon <> null && lat <> 0 && lon <> 0) {
            //We need to query the Stores that are closest
            obj.studioList = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, Phone, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingStateCode, BillingPostalCode,
                              DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:lat,:lon), 'mi') dist FROM Account 
                              WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:lat,:lon), 'mi') < distance AND
                              RecordType.Name = 'Stores'
                              ORDER BY DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:lat,:lon), 'mi') ASC
                              LIMIT 10];  
            if (obj.storeList.size() == 0) {
                obj.err = 'No Stores found within 10 miles';
            }
        } else {
            obj.studioList = NULL;
            obj.err = 'Error:  Distance cant calculated for this record(' + lat + ', ' + lon + ')';
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I am stuck on how to take this and create a new REST resource/service. These are the small changes I have made(which I am not sure is correct). First off all the contact logic is removed because the parameters are already passed from the url. Here is what I have

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/getStores/*') //added this line
global class StoreReturner{
   public List<Account> storesList {get; set;}
   public String err {get; set;}
@HttpGet
public static StoresReturner initClass(){
RestRequest request = RestContext.request;

//I dont think any of the below variables are corrrect. I dont think this is the right way of doing it.
    String latitude = request.requestURI.substring(
          request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    String longitude = request.requestURI.substring(
          request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+2);

String distance = request.requestURI.substring(
          request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+3);
String postal = request.requestURI.substring(
          request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+4);

 StoresReturner obj = new StoresReturner();

            //Initialize
            obj.storeList = new List<Account>();

 if (latitude <> null && longitude <> null && latitude <> 0 && longitude <> 0) {
                //We need to query the Stores that are closest
                obj.studioList = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, Phone, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingStateCode, BillingPostalCode,
                                  DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,:longitude), 'mi') dist FROM Account 
                                  WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,:longitude), 'mi') < 10 AND
                                  RecordType.Name = 'Stores'
                                  ORDER BY DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,:longitude), 'mi') ASC
                                  LIMIT 10];  
                if (obj.storeList.size() == 0) {
                    obj.err = 'No Stores found within' + distance + ' miles';
                }
            } else {
                obj.studioList = NULL;
                obj.err = 'Error:  Distance cant calculated for this record(' + latitude + ', ' + longitude + ')';
            }
            return obj;


}


}
```

Any sugesstions, code samples, corrections would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to the get the parameters from the URL for HTTP **get** method use the below code snippet

```
RestContext.request.params.get('<urlparamname>');
```

Example to get the latitude to use below

```
Double latitude = double.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('latitude'));

Double longitude = double.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('longitude'));

String distance = RestContext.request.params.get('distance');

String postalCode = RestContext.request.params.get('postal_code');

String country = RestContext.request.params.get('country');
```

Based on your JSON as below, the apex class will be as shown

```
[{
"name": "Great Center",
"location": {
    "lat": 90.7,
    "lng": -143.5
},
  "address": "125 Fake Blvd,Grand Rapids,TX 23456 US",
   "distance": "3 miles",
   "Phone": "852 - 446 - 3569",
   "StudioLocationId": "XYZTY",
   "Studio Type": "Indoor"
 }]
```

The apex class is as shown below

```
public class StoresReturner {

  public String name;
  public Location location;
  public String address;
  public String distance;
  public String Phone;
  public String StudioLocationId;
  public String Studio Type;

  public class Location {
     public Double lat;
     public Double lng;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohith, thanks for your help. I guess what I am also stuck is in my code would I need to do anything extra to return the response in the format given?stores = [
{
name: ' Great Center,
location: {lat: 90.7, lng: -143.5},
address: ‘125 Fake Blvd, Grand Rapids, TX 23456 US’,
distance : 3 miles,
Phone : 852-446-3569,
StudioLocationId: XYZTY,
Studio Type: Indoor
},

Comment: Use a tool like https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to generate a class equivalent for your response

Comment: so you are saying when I return "obj" i should create another method that is generated by the joson2apex tool and return that newly formatted obj?"

Comment: Something along same lines. You can create a wrapper class and form that as return object

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: Here is one from very old post http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2012/12/writing-test-classes-for-apex-rest.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107647/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-user3688231).

Comment: I added a new code in the chat